# Storage(memory) alternatives to GAE datastore(memcache) persistent across cron jobs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Assume an app that collects real-time temperature data for various cities around the world every 10 minutes.

**Using the following GAE datastore model,**

```
class City(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class DailyTempData(db.Model):
    date = db.DateProperty()
    temp_readings = db.ListProperty(float, indexed=False) # appended every 10 minutes
```

**and a cron.yaml as so,**

```
cron:
- description: read temperature
  url: /cron/read_temps
  schedule: every 10 minutes
```

I am already hitting GAE's daily free quota for datastore writes, and I'm looking for ways to get around this problem.

I'm thinking of reducing my datastore writes by persisting the temperature data only at the end of each day, which will effectively reduce the daily write volume (for each city) from 144 times to 1.

One way to do this is to use memcache as a temporary scratchpad, but due to the possibility of random data evictions, I could well lose all my data for the day. (Aside question: from experience, how often does unplanned eviction really happen?)

**Questions are as follows:**

1. Is there such a memory/storage facility (persistent and guaranteed across cron jobs) that would allow me to reduce datastore writes as described?
2. If not, what could be some alternative solutions?

The only other requirement would be that the temperature readings must be accessible (for serving to client-side) any given time of day.

Comment: not sure this deserved a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also change your model, so that a huge object is stored for each execution or the cron. Not just for each city, I mean.
For example, say the object is called Measures... A Measures item will contain a List of all your measures for the corresponding time. Store them as non-indexed properties and you should have no problems... And also just 144 writes a day.

For the reading part... Use memcache to store the Measures items, as a good usage pattern.

Comment: Thanks, tried this out too yesterday. I think it's the best solution. Used a dict with a {'city' : [today's list of temp readings], ...} format, all pickled into one blob. Interesting how Google is forcing us to this solution by restricting our datastore usage.

Answer (score 2):

The only guaranteed  storage in the datastore.

As to memcache evictions - it's depends on what is going on, in your app and in google appengine land, evictions could be within a minute or two or after hours.  In my appengine instances I usually have oldest items sitting at about 2 hours old.  But it all depends and you just can't rely on it.

tasks queues payload is about 10K.

You could just write a blob (containing all cities measured in the 10min interval) and then reprocess it and unpick it and write out the city details at the end of the day.

When you say clients must be able to  access temperature readings, do you mean just the current or all the readings for the day.

Comment: I meant all readings for the day (query against a particular city and date range, including readings available so far today). If I understand your suggestion correctly, your solution seems to come with a penalty of increased read volume (by a worst case factor 144 times to 1, since the temperature readings of one city are now distributed among 144 blobs)? But since read issues are more amenable to solving using memcache (than writes are), backing the 10-minute interval blobs with memcache should solve my problem?

Comment: I'll try this out for now and see if the read performance will turn out to be acceptable